# JavaScript - Apply function to a specific div in a collection of divs with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

When I hover over `.winner-container`, the JS function tells `.headline` to move out of `.winner-container` and it tells `.bottom` to move into `.winner-container`. When I unhover, the opposite occurs.

The problem is, I'm going to have hundreds of these containers, all with the `.winner-container` class. So I've realised that when I hover over one of the containers, the function is applied to hundreds of different containers all at once. I only want the function to be applied to the specific container I'm hovering over. I could do this by giving each container an id, and then write new JS code for each id, but that would require a lot of work, considering there will be hundreds of these divs. Is there a more elegant solution?

**https://jsfiddle.net/6sm6ajht/**

HTML

```
<div class="winner-container">
  <div class="top">
    <h4 class="headline">SME Example 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="winner-words">
      <h6>SME Examle 1 is a technology company.</h6>
      <h6><a>Learn more...</a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="winner-container">
  <div class="top">
    <h4 class="headline">SME Example 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="winner-words">
      <h6>SME Examle 2 is an e-commerce company.</h6>
      <h6><a>Learn more...</a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.winner-container {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid #074E68;
}

.winner-container,
.top,
.bottom {
  width: 10em;
  height: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 12em;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.top .headline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.top-up .headline {
  top: -2.5em;
}

.bottom-up.bottom {
  top: 0em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".winner-container").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(".top").addClass('top-up');
  $(".bottom").addClass('bottom-up');
});

$(".winner-container").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(".top").removeClass('top-up');
  $(".bottom").removeClass('bottom-up');
});
```

Comment: you  should add an id for the tag you need  to manage individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great opportunity for the `$(this)` selector. Because there are many identical elements but you only want each event handler to refer to that particular element, you can use `$(this)` and use a relative selector like `.children` to target other elements relative to the `this` element.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/batpd6k1/)

```
$(".winner-container").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).children(".top").addClass('top-up');
  $(this).children(".bottom").addClass('bottom-up');
});

$(".winner-container").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).children(".top").removeClass('top-up');
  $(this).children(".bottom").removeClass('bottom-up');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your selectors for .top and .bottom to `$(this).find('.top')` and `$(this).find('.bottom')`.

this in the context of the event handler is the element on which the event occurred.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the $(this) selector in order to specify that you only want the current element to be the scope of your directives:

```
$(".winner-container").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).children(".top").addClass('top-up');
  $(this).children(".bottom").addClass('bottom-up');
});

$(".winner-container").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).children(".top").removeClass('top-up');
  $(this).children(".bottom").removeClass('bottom-up');
});
```

Comment: Downvoted because your answer is just a copy of dogui's.

Comment: I di not read this guy's answer, otherwise I would have had no interest in answering at all. We posted our answers at the same time. That will teach me trying to help others.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".winner-container")` will target all element with class `winner-container` and add an event to each of them, that's why you have two elements but you only need to define it once.

Same as `$('.top')`, this will target all class called top, you need to use `$(this).find('.top')` inside the event to target ONLY the current element and use find() to search inside this element, find `top` and `bottom` add or remove class do whatever you want.

```js
$(".winner-container").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).find('.top').addClass('top-up');
  $(this).find('.bottom').addClass('bottom-up');
});

$(".winner-container").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).find('.top').removeClass('top-up');
  $(this).find('.bottom').removeClass('bottom-up');
});
```

```css
.winner-container {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid #074E68;
}

.winner-container,
.top,
.bottom {
  width: 10em;
  height: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 12em;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.top .headline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.top-up .headline {
  top: -2.5em;
}

.bottom-up.bottom {
  top: 0em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="winner-container">
  <div class="top">
    <h4 class="headline">SME Example 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="winner-words">
      <h6>SME Examle 1 is a technology company.</h6>
      <h6><a>Learn more...</a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="winner-container">
  <div class="top">
    <h4 class="headline">SME Example 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="winner-words">
      <h6>SME Examle 2 is an e-commerce company.</h6>
      <h6><a>Learn more...</a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```